# using a values.string res as a pattern for String.format()

Tags: java, android, string.format

In my Android app, I want to use a values.string resource as the first parameter for String.format();

But R.my_pattern_res is an integer. How can I extract the string out of it so I could do the fallowing?

```
private void foo(int bar, float buzz){ 


 Toast.addText(
    ctx,
    String.format(R.string(R.my_pattern_res, bar, buzz),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

### [String#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int))

Use it to convert an `int` value into its `String` form.

```
String.format(R.string(String.valueOf(R.my_pattern_res), bar, buzz)
```

Comment: R.my_pattern_res is a resourceid in R.java  which can be retrieved using  getString(), String.valueOf(R.my_pattern_res) wont resolve it to string

Answer (score 1):

You can use like following

```
  private void foo(int bar, float buzz) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, String.format(getString(R.string.my_pattern_res), bar, buzz), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```